# Redirect 301 using Rewrite module

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect (301) URLs using `URL rewrite` module (IIS 8.5).

Here is what I am trying to do:

**Redirect this URL structure:**

```
mySite.com/area.aspx?id=1
```

**To this structure:**

```
mySite.com/area/1
```

I was trying to do this but it does not work

```
<rewrite>
     <rules>
      <rule name="301 Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^area.aspx?id=([0-9]+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="area/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try escaping the `?` or using the character class, e.g. `pattern="^area.aspx[?]=([0-9]+)"`, and use `{C:1}` instead of `{R:0}`.

Comment: Does not work, but thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are using `{HTTP_HOST}` to match with, which does not contain a path.

You could just use the `url` attribute rather than creating a condition for this.

```
<rule name="301 Redirect to area">
    <match url="^area\.aspx?id=([0-9]+)"/>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="area/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

On a side note, don't forget to add a no-cache directive to the headers or you will have a difficult time with browsers caching the redirect and giving you incorrect results after you change the redirect rules.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <redirectHeaders>
            <!-- This is to ensure that clients don't cache the 301 itself - 
            this is dangerous because the 301 can't change when put in 
            place once it is cached -->
            <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/>
        </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```